# javax.microedition.xml.rpc.Operation.newInstance returns null - JSR172

Tags: web-services, java-me, client, jsr172

I am using the Sun Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2 to generate web services client stubs.  When running the generated code, the method `Operation.newInstance` method always returns null.  The generated code is:

```
Operation op = Operation.newInstance(_qname_a, _type_b, _type_c);
_prepOperation(op);
...
```

`op` is null after the call which then causes an exception in `_prepOperation()`.

Does the JSR172 library need to be initialized before use?